# Is it possible to read the value of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable in postinst?

Tags: cmake, cpack

Just wanted to ask if it is possible to read the value of [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) variable in [postinst](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA) script? The goal is to have `postinst` script to read a file in `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/myapp` folder and, based on the content of the file read, to generate a file in  `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/etc/myapp` folder.  I'd like to avoid relying on absolute paths.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

Calling `env` from `postinst` gives good information:

```
DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_DEBUG=0
DPKG_COLORS=never
DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME=postinst
DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE=myapp
DPKG_RUNNING_VERSION=1.19.0.5
DPKG_FRONTEND_LOCKED=true
DPKG_ROOT=
DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_ARCH=armhf
DPKG_ADMINDIR=/var/lib/dpkg
DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE_REFCOUNT=1
```

`DPKG_ROOT` is probably what I need.  It seems that `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is not related to `postinst`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking at the moment of execution `postinst` there is no CMake variables (and they definitely never be in the `env` output). So, the way to do what you want is to *generate* your `postinst` script (from `postinst.in` file) using [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) function. In the template file you can refer CMake variables, so being rendered your script would contain "hardcoded" literals instead. And that is quite normal.

But, take in account the following:

- `cpack` uses [`CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) variable